# Find the birthdаte using age and date of die

Tags: r

```
person_died_at <- c(22)
person_date_died <- c("2015-05-10")
```

I need to say that the person died on his birthday and calculate birthdate, using converting to Date, POSIXlt.

Comment: `as.Date(person_date_died) - lubridate::years(person_died_at)`

Answer (score 2):

```
person_died <- as.POSIXlt("2015-05-10")
names(unclass(as.POSIXlt("2015-05-10")))
[1] "sec"    "min"    "hour"   "mday"   "mon"    "year"   "wday"   "yday"  
         "isdst"  "zone"   "gmtoff"
a$year <- a$year - 22
person_birthdate <- a
person_birthdate
 "1993-05-10 CDT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `as.POSIXlt`

```
person_died_at <- 22
person_date_died <- "2015-05-10"

temp <- as.POSIXlt(person_date_died, tz = "UTC")
temp$year <- temp$year - person_died_at
temp
#[1] "1993-05-10 UTC"
```